# Django/rest: When I'm trying to select a user, I get error `(1048, "Column cannot be null")`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `django 1.11.5` and python 3.5.

Using `rest-framework`, I want to search a patient having `uid`.

When I'm trying to have a serializer with only one field I get the error `(1048, "Column 'yearofbirth' cannot be null")`.

I don't want to save anything, I just want to get all user's info having the given uid.

Is there any solution to fix this?

I believe that occurs because I'm using post method. How to use get via browser and not using `curl`?

serializers.py

```
class GetUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source='uid')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', )
```

views.py

```
class GetUser(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = GetUserSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = GetUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        # Check format and unique constraint
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, \
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        data = serializer.data


        if User.objects.filter(uid = data['id']).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(uid = data['id'])
            resp = {"user":{"uid":user.uid, "firstname":user.firstname, "yearofbirth": user.yearofbirth, \
                            "lastnames": user.lastname, "othernames": user.othernames}}
            return Response(resp, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:

            resp = {"error": "User not found"}
            return Response(resp, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True,default="0")
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    othernames = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    yearofbirth = models.SmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1900),
                                           MaxValueValidator(2018)], null = False
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're "using POST method?" The part of your views.py you shared seems to show behavior intended to respond to a GET request (which would be the appropriate type of request for a detail action like you're describing).

Comment: @souldeux When I run the api via browser, I see a `post` button. Yes, I set `get` because I want to use `get`.

Comment: The browsable api runs more requests than is immediately apparent. For that reason your serializer and view need to handle them all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323159/django-rest-framework-get-serializer-class-called-several-times-with-wrong-v

Comment: @souldeux Thank you for providing me this info! Really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! I will post that as an answer, if it has resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Making a GET request through the browsable API actually makes a few additional calls behind the scenes, with different methods. If your serializer isn't equipped to handle them it'll cause an error like you're seeing here. Check out this SO post for more detail: [Django Rest Framework: `get_serializer_class` called several times, with wrong value of request method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323159/django-rest-framework-get-serializer-class-called-several-times-with-wrong-v)